# rails destroy model command not visible in git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git

Just starting out with rails and git and have run across an issue where I had generated a model, however just for a start have decided to use scaffolding for my first attempt. In this case I ran the following command

```
rails destroy model company
```

I am working in a dev branch I have created, after running the above command i checked my repo with git status and it said that there were no changes to commit. I checked that my model.rb file had been removed, so switched to my master branch and ran the command:

```
git merge dev
```

however it says that everything is up to date, even though I have changes in my dev branch which doesn't seem to have registered in my git repo.

Have I done something wrong, or is there something I am misunderstanding with rails to do with the generate and destroy commands?

Comment: did you check your .gitignore file?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, .gitignore file is relatively clean only ignoring various logs, tmp dir, bundle config